# Why is the load connected to the batteries instead of the load output of the controller?

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I bought a small photovoltaic kit to do some experiments.
It is composed of:

- PV panels
- charge controller
- batteries
- inverter

In the controller's manual there is this connection diagram:

[image]

It makes sense to me, because the batteries are connected to the battery output, and the load to the load output. In this way, the controller knows how much current is flowing to the batteries and how much to the load. Furthermore, I can use some features of the controller like the button to connect/disconnect the load and read the current flowing to the load on the display. The manual also states the rating current is 20 A.

But the seller of the kit suggests another wiring scheme:

[image]

As you can see, the load (inverter) is connected in parallel to the batteries and the load output of the controller is floating.

I don't understand why they suggest this way. You can't connect/disconnect the load, you can't measure the current flowing to the load, and also the charger is "fooled", since current drawn by the load is seen as charging current flowing into the batteries.

I wrote to the manufacturer asking for clarification, but they just answered: "connect the products like the picture we sent you". Great, but this isn't enough for me.

Can you please explain the differences between the two configurations, and if the second one is better, why?

### UPDATE

Just to clarify after the first comments.
I was not so clear above about the 20 A ratings of the controller: of course is too low to connect the inverter to its outputs (that requires more than 100 A). But, given a properly designed system, should not the first circuit preferable?

Comment: Comparing the charge controller's load circuit current rating with the inverter's current requirement (around 100A peak) will give you a clue. For very small loads like a few LED lights, you can use the load circuit.

Comment: Assuming lossless operation, what is the peak input current to the second vendor's inverter? How does that compare to the controller current rating?

Comment: @user_1818839 yep, but this seems to me a wrong selection of the controller. I mean, if the inverter requires such an high current, are we sure it does not affect the charging current? The controller sees this current as flowing into the batteries!

Comment: @greybeard I understand your point, like user_1818839. I'm aware the ratings are incompatible. But I wonder if this is a bad design...

Comment: If you want to be able to use the charge controller to turn the inverter on & off, then you could use a *large* relay (or low-voltage "contactor") connected to the controller's load output to switch the power to the inverter. But this wouldn't help you with measuring current drawn by the inverter. Those solar chargers rarely seem to perform "coulomb counting" to report the battery charge state though, and seem to base their display more on the battery voltage than anything else.

Comment: You may have another problem; unless that controller is explicitly designed to handle LFP batteries, according to its datasheet, you must assume it isn't. Most of them are lead-acid only, and lead acid batteries are more tolerant of abuse.

Comment: Putting that big relay or contactor inside the charge controller would make it significantly bigger & more expensive, but only benefit a minority of users. Anyone who's using that charge controller for low-voltage lighting doesn't need anything more than what's already there - it's only when you want to hook up a heavy current draw load like the inverter that you need the extra current handling capabilities.

Comment: @user_1818839 it can charge LFP batteries, it's stated in the manual. But still I don't understand how it can correctly charge the battery if the inverter draws the current on the same port of the battery...

Comment: @brhans ok, so you're saying this kind of connection is common and correct, right? Can you please explain *how* can it work? I'm talking about the current flowing from the battery port of the controller to both batteries and load at the same time

Comment: Yes - the current from the charge controller is being divided between the batteries and the inverter - assuming that the panels can even supply more current than the inverter requires - and the batteries then charge slower than they would without the inverter running. Otherwise if the inverter needs more current than the panels can supply, then it draws current from both the charge controller and the batteries at the same time, and the batteries are discharging (although at a slower rate then they would if the charge controller wasn't also contributing).

Answer (score 1):

The inverter is rated for 600W continuous, 1200W peak, which is 50A continuous, 100A peak. The charge controller is rated for 20A. That is probably why the seller doesn't recommend wiring the inverter through the charge controller.

It is also possible that the seller originally planned to use a different charge controller because not all of them have load outputs.

Comment: Yep it makes sense. What if the controller load output rating was compatible with the inverter requirements? Is it worth to connect in such a way?

Comment: @Mark yes, so that you can get the load features of the controller, like disconnecting the load when the battery is too low, and displaying the amount of power used.

Comment: @Mark you can make a solar energy system without a charge controller at all, but it is very easy to charge the batteries too much or discharge them too much - either one ruins the batteries. The most important purpose of the charge controller is to automatically prevent that from happening.

Comment: That's the point beyond my question. I made several battery charges (not for solar system, though) and when there is a load connected on the batteries, it *may* fool the charger (it may think, for example, the battery is draining so much current because it's quite empty).

Comment: @Mark It may, but it shouldn't matter because either way the charger will let through the full charge, right? Unless the load is so strong it thinks the battery is below 0% and won't charge it for safety reasons. (Then your batteries are too small for that load, anyway)

Comment: Good point. I was afraid also about timed charging sequence. Unfortunately there so few information about how those solar chargers work, hence my doubts.

Comment: @Mark Lead-acid batteries are pretty lenient with charging. There are no timed charges - the charger just monitors the voltage and shuts off when it is high enough. I believe lithium-ion/lithium-polymer batteries are pickier. I don't know about the proper charging of LiFePO4 which is what your diagram says you have.